# How to git submodule level 1 update without using recursive?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

```
<project>
.....<submodules1>
..........<sub1>
.............<submodules2>
.................<sub11>
......................<src>
.........................<submodules3>
.............................<sub2>
....<submodules4>
.........<sub41>
.............<src>
................<submodules5>
```

I initially cloned project with `git clone "ssh:..."`
I tried to update submodules in sub1 with
`git submodule update --init`
but it just initializes folders of submodules2 without any  contents.

I don't want to use recursive as it updates submodules3. Can I know a way to update submodules with 1 level deep.(I am not asking about history, I need submodules 1 level)

Comment: you should add the git-submodules tag for more attention. Have you tried going into submodule1 and done an initalization of submodule2 from there?

Comment: Yes I tried some thing like that, cloned <project>, then cd <submodules1> and updated to depth=1, git submodule update --init --depth=1 
And cd <sub1/submdules2> and git submodule update --init --depth=1.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a script which would use [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --init
```

Then, for each of those submodule path (like `submodule1/sub1`), you need to repeat that, in order to initialize `submodule2/sub11`.

The idea that `git submodule foreach`, unless given `--recursive`, will stop at the direct submodules listed in its `.gitmodules`.

Something like (not tested)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize direct submodules
git submodule update --init

# Initialize direct submodule dependencies
git submodule foreach --quiet "
    if [ $(git submodule | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && (( GIT_SUBMODULE_DEPTH < 2 )); then
        export GIT_SUBMODULE_DEPTH=$((GIT_SUBMODULE_DEPTH + 1))
        git submodule update --init
    fi
"
```